# Combine PHP and jQuery to loop over pictures, match IDs, and output images in slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slideshow

I have the following piece of code. What it does is, it loops over all pictures in a directory and compares them to IDs previously saved before. Works fine so far.

Now I don't just want to display the pictures but include them in one of these fancy jQuery Slideshows (here I want to use the Cycle Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). The PHP code is executed on server side which is why the slideshow does not work as wanted so far, I guess. Is that correct? Any idea how I could combine it so that the slider works properly? Or is that not possible in this combination?

**EDIT: surrounded PHP code with basic jQuery Slideshow Cycle2**

```
<body>
<div class="cycle-slideshow">

    <?php 
    $selection = $_GET["selection"];
    $selectionAsArray = explode(",", $selection);
    //print_r($selectionAsArray);
    $dir="../../img";
    $againAllPics = scandir($dir);
    //set counter to -2 to skip . & ..  & other element in Folder and start
      //with first pictureId = 1

    //loop over all selected Ids and compare them with the counter (Id) 
    //of the freshly loaded pictures from the directory; display them if Ids match
    $i=0;
    for($i; $i < count($selectionAsArray); $i++) {
    $counter =  -2;
        foreach ($againAllPics as $pic) {
        $picinfo = pathinfo($dir."/".$pic); 
            if($selectionAsArray[$i] == $counter) {
            ?>
             <img src="<?php echo $picinfo['dirname']."/".$picinfo['basename'];?>" 
                     width="960" height="540" />
            <?php

            };      
        $counter++;
        }
    }
    ?>

</div>
</body>
```

**EDIT: HTML output**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="cycle-slideshow">

<img src="../../img/Folie4.jpg" width="960" height="540" />
<img src="../../img/Folie5.jpg" width="960" height="540" />

</div>
</body>
```

If I put this in an HTML file, it works fine.

Comment: What _does not work_?

Comment: looking at the docs, you need to wrap your images in `<div class="slideshow">...</div>`. Have you also included the required js/jQuery scripts?

Comment: Yes, as I stated the Code does work. The problem is that the slideshow does not work as wanted because on server side the HTML output is prepared and then somehow the jQuery stuff is not included properly on client side anymore (?!) which results in displaying the selected images just on top of each other instead of the nice slideshow output. Of course it is surrounded by the respective slideshow tags. Should have added that, sorry.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the html output, included the js/jQuery code? If you images are showing, but not displaying properly in the slideshow, it might be how the js/jQuery code is included.

Comment: The problem is, that the slideshow is not executed as if I simply include the pictures in an HTML file with <img.../> <img.../> The pictures are simply displayed above each other. No effects whatsoever. Jquery is included correctly ;)

Comment: Ok, just found out that when I refresh the page it works with the selection. Still think it is a server-side/client-side issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code already outputs the `img` tag, to give you a good idea of how to combine the jQuery plugin would work this is what I would do:

View the source of the basic example: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html and then replace where you see the the `img` tags with your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 232px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="slideshow">

<?php 
    $selection = $_GET["selection"];
    $selectionAsArray = explode(",", $selection);
    $dir="../../img";
    $againAllPics = scandir($dir);
    //loop over all selected Ids and compare them with the counter (Id) of 
    //the freshly loaded pictures from the directory; display them if Ids match
    $i=0;
    for($i; $i < count($selectionAsArray); $i++) {
    //skip the . and .. elements
    $counter =  -2;
        foreach ($againAllPics as $pic) {
        $picinfo = pathinfo($dir."/".$pic); 
            if($selectionAsArray[$i] == $counter) {
            ?>
            <img u="image" src="<?php echo $picinfo['dirname']
           ."/".$picinfo['basename'];?>" width="200" height="200" />
            <?php

            };      
        $counter++;
        }
    }
    ?>


        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should just be able to run this as you do your script: Save it as `slideshow.php` and put it in the same location as the script you posted, then visit `http://www.yourwebsite.com/your/dir/slideshow.php`.

I have made the images 200x200px as per the demo so you may need to write some code that changes the sizes base upon the relevant width and height ratios. Hope this gives you an idea of how to combine jQuery, HTML and PHP though.

You are right that PHP code gets executed server-side, and that the rest will get executed client-side. When your server gets a request for the page the PHP will generate the HTML that then gets passed to you as part of the page. Javascript will then get executed by your browser.

Comment: Thanks, however it does not solve the problem. Could you have a look again, please? Thanks a ton.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: Using Chrome, however if I'm using the HTML output of the .php file everything works as it should. So it's probably not about the browser.

Comment: And you get no errors in your Chrome console? If your PHP is working then then you need to make sure that there are no Javascript errors.